# How to observe game stats over a whole session?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating Tic Tac Toe in Angular, and I'd like to track stats from the game over the session, i.e. stats that don't reset when a new board object is created.

I have a `TicTacToeComponent` that creates a new board and that's about it, and the `TicTacToeBoard` object has all the fields and logic for the game. The user can create a new board using a button tied to `newGame()` in `TicTacToeComponent` or of course a new board is created when you load the page. Obviously tracking stats in the board object won't make sense. I was thinking a session object that creates each game is best, but I'm not sure how I would be able to inject the stats from that into the `TicTacToeComponent` template... How can I track stats over a whole user session which might have multiple games created? Is this some kind of observable pattern? How can I implement this?

```
app
 |--tic-tac-toe
 |        |--tic-tac-toe.component.* (imports and instantiates board)
 |
 |--app.component.* (routes to welcome screen and t-t-t.component
 |
 |--tic-tac-toe-board.ts (board class, probably should be moved)
```

Solving this might also allow me to keep a game even when routing to another page and back.

[Source code](https://github.com/mosherc/tic-tac-toe)

Comment: How persistent should these stats be?  Should they persist when the user refreshes the page?  When they close and re-open the browser?  Tracked across different browsers?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Hmm at first I'd like it to persist for as long as the AppComponent is instantiated, then I'd transition to cookies, then maybe a database. So initially that would just be in between refreshes since it's a SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `Stats` component and whenever a game comes to an end, you send an event from the `TicTacToeComponent` with the relevant information (i.e. game won by player X) and store that in a property of the `Stats` component.

This would allow you to keep track of different games, but obviously all the information would be lost if the page is refreshed. If you want a more complex solution, you need to implement it server-side.

Comment: Ok great, this is what I'm looking for. Would Angular.io have good docs on event emitting, or can you point me somewhere? Not too familiar with events but I've seen them used

Comment: You can have a look at https://angular.io/guide/rx-library, which is the most common way to handle custom events in angular

Comment: I just looked up some stuff too, seems that since I am using AppComponent as the parent, you can't output data to the <router-outlet>. I could maybe make the session component a parent and the game a child and it would work

Comment: Yes that would definitely be an option. It would also make sense logically, as the session should have awareness of all the games that have been played, while an individual game shouldn't know anything about other games that have been played previously

Comment: that actually worked! I made the app route to a SessionComponent that has a TicTacToeComponent in the template. Using the `@Output` from TTTComp and listening for the event in SessionComp allowed me to track the board and thus total turns even when new games are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you may not want to use a database, you can use components to create variables in localstorage `localStorage.setItem('gamesWon', gamesWon++);`

Then you can make an observable or just a getter anywhere in your app to get the data with `localStorage.getItem('gamesWon);`

So far, I have not found a good way to sufficiently store indestructable objects in memory without some sort of database  or using local storage. Following this thread to see if others have found a good solution.

Comment: Yeah that would have been my next step to use local storage. I was hoping there was a purely Angular way to do this by having some object created at the highest AppComponent level that tracks all the games in the background.

Comment: Technically that is all possible. If you have a pretty simple component structure, you can just use and event emitter to send data to a parent component. However, you have to make sure its a component that is not destroyed often.

Comment: Yeah, basically I created a new parent component that wasn't the root, then put the game as the child of that. I pass all the individual game stats I need to the parent, and then I push the session stats back to the child (since that's where it will display in the template). I also did local storage like you suggested, so now it's working perfectly, thanks!